# Not able to find data in mongoose using find query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my application i want the user to enter username and password and then username is first check in the database using find query and if username finds then it renders the new page to the user.
The problem is if i enter a wrong username and password then it also renders a new page and the page is also not completely load.
please tell me what is the mistke.

In app.js I have written:

```
app.post('/profile',users.login);
```

in users.js i have written:

```
exports.login=function(req,res){
   console.log("login called");
   PersonalInfo.findOne({ name:req.params.userName}, function(err,data){
      if(err)
      {
          console.log("find is not done");
          console.log(data);
      }
      else{
          res.render("/profilearea.ejs");
      }
        })
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `findOne` query fails to find a matching document, it's not considered an error.  Instead, the 'not found' case is indicated by the `data` parameter to the `findOne` callback being `null`.

Your `findOne` callback function's code should look something like this instead:

```
  if(err || !data)
  {
      console.log("find is not done");
  }
  else{
      res.render("/profilearea.ejs");
  }
```

Comment: PersonalInfo.findOne({ name:'amna'}, function(err,posts){ // }} the name amna is present in my database but this also prints "find is not done " ...... @JohnyHK

Comment: @ana The code in your comment has `posts` as the second argument.  Is that just a typo?

Comment: PersonalInfo.findOne({ name:'amna'}, function(err,post){ // }} I want to ask that the post is that data which in find by find query?? @JohnyHK